# c# and internet key

Tags: c#, .net

I have a software written on WPF using c# and .NET 3.5 that need to connect to internet for exchanging data with some web-services.

For testing purpose I used the a sim and the vodafone mobile internet stick key usb, and the vodafone mobile broadband software.

To have some control on the internet connection  I simply launch the program vodafone mobile broadband inside c# using the system.process classes. Once configured in automatic mode and not requesting the pin of the sim the software seems working correctly.

I am forced to close the application to kill the .exe software. Everything seems working for a while. But randomly after a while the vodafone mobile turns itself on manual connection so it does not connect to the internet anymore.

Mobile broadband does not come with a seat of api and it is not possible to give AT command to open the connection.

So my question is what device can I use that have C# api to allow a pc to connect to internet to that is possible to open programmatically a connection to internet without user interaction so totally calleable and manageable by C#.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Please clarify it and if you have a question about a block of code, post it, you must attempt to do it yourself before we can help you.

Comment: API?  Unless Vodafone provide you with an API to interact with their USB dongle; no.  Other than that it sounds like you're asking how to run a process from C# - which you've already figured out.  You write your application *expecting* for a connection to be present, and display a helpful error message if a WAN connection is not available - thereby giving the user the ability to fix it themselves.

Comment: I guess you cannot fully control how your users device is connected to the internet. Imagine the device tethered to another device instead of using a built in modem. Usually programs just inform the user that they need to be connected to the internet to use it.

Comment: the problem is this everything works fine for a while by launching vodafone mobile broadband using process. After I finish using internet I kill  the process mobilebroadband.exe. The first time it works, the second idem, the third or randomly when I lauch the  mobilebroadband.exe that opens the vodafone software and try to connect to internet if is configured to starts in manual mode so I need the user to push a button on vodafone software. This happens even if the first time I configured the vodafone connection software to open an internet connection without user input.

Comment: I would guess that the vodafone connection software wants to inform the user that a potential malicious software repeatedly connects to the internet.

Comment: both of you guessed the point. I cannot fully control the software (I can only lauch it and kill it). But I would like to have internet connection device / software on a pc that is fully controllable by a set of api

Comment: @user730712 You could inspect the default system internet connection as configured in IE - I admit I have no idea how to do this from C#.

Comment: @Andreas  you're right but the software on the PC I use it is developed to be used by elderly people that have still problem clicking on a touch screen button large as this text so I cannot train them to reconfigure the vodafone key.

Answer (score 2):

Don't automate things on a user's machine that they expect to have control over - having an app automatically open up transient internet connections is so clearly a security risk most people will immediately delete your app.

I want to be able to disconnect the internet on my computer without worrying about one or more apps trying to re-initialise the modem/ethernet card/etc.

Your app relies on the connection - the connection does not rely on your app.

So basically, IMHO, don't do it.

*Update* So it's for elderly people and I can understand what you're saying - but I still don't think it's a good reason for pursuing it as a solution.  App automation is so flaky, especially when considering that the client might be updated without your knowledge; or the user might be more advanced technically and choose to use a different modem.

In that case, it'll probably be better to investigate whether the Vodafone software can be configured to auto-run and stay always-on, then ensure whoever is responsible for installing it configures it correctly.